# Every perfect Polish space is a continuous 1-1 image of the Baire space

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, the-baire-space

I am learning descriptive set theory by myself and stumble upon this theorem without proof, could somebody help me prove it:

Every perfect Polish space is a continuous 1-1 image of the Baire space $\omega^\omega$.

Thanks

Comment: **Theorem** $\mathbf{1.17}$ of [this Postscript file](http://www.math.uic.edu/~marker/math512/dst.ps) gives a proof that every Polish space is a continuous image of $\omega^\omega$. If you examine it closely, you’ll see that if $X$ is perfect, the continuous function is actual an injection. It suffices to observe that if $X$ is perfect, the sets $U_\sigma$ can be chosen so that they are all distinct. For this you should go back to **Lemma** $\mathbf{1.6}$ and show that if $X$ is perfect, the sets $U_n$ can be chosen to be distinct.